# React / Axios send infinite number of requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, axios

I'm fetching data from my backend api when component mount and can do it successfuly but my React app keeps sending requests to the server causing it to slow down. I used useEffect hook, but I'm getting the same result without using the hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
   axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/food_category/')
  .then(response => {
   setFoodCategory(response.data);
   console.log(response.data);
})});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Each time you use setFoodCategory the component is mounted again and useEffect is executed. Try useEffect( () => { ... }, []). The empty array parameter at the end will execute useEffect only once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you give no dependencies to the `useEffect` hook, it will execute every time your component renders (which will happen infinitely because you set the state after getting data and thus your component rerenders).

Check out the second argument of `useEffect` in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) to learn more about it.

An empty dependencies array indicates the `useEffect` will act as a mount and only executes once.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Do mount stuff here such as executing your request.
}, []);
```

Comment: And how can I watch the other props? so I can execute it again?